# Typescript: How to filter between two similar interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function that can receive a couple of similar objects. Something like this:

```
interface BannerProps {
  type: typeof possibleBannerTypes[number];
  data?: unknown
}
```

Then I have a simple chain of `if/else if` statements that returns different UI components based on the type parameter.

```
function test(bannerData: EmailBounceBannerProps | BannerProps) {
    if (bannerData.type === 'anotherBanner') {
        // do something
    } else if (bannerData.type === 'emailBounce') {
        console.log(bannerData.data.reason)
    }
}
```

Objects with the `type` property set to a specific value (`emailBounce`) has a data property that I would also like to type so that I can use type checking and Intellisense in VS Code.

```
interface EmailBounceBannerProps extends BannerProps{
  type: 'emailBounce';
  data: {
    reason: string;
  };
}
```

However, I can't seem to make it work, typescript doesn't seem to be able to figure out when `type === 'emailBounce`, the `data` property becomes populated.

**I've created a small snippet on the TypeScript playground to illustrate this problem:**

[Code snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBADiCECWAjANgUwEIEMxiYBOAKgJ5yYQwC8MA2gOSYC2uy62IArmMJowA0MRvhBQAFsTwFijALoBuAFDLkYKMQBmufjBmEiABSIg41AN7KYMKBUwAuW-ZBb4iFBhz5D5ShHowbhZUYiVrGAATXChcAH4nXgBrMBAAdzBlAF9VdU0iHT0AUTYOLl5+A2ITM2pMAA9NMEjqKuNTcysbO0onZlLOHj4BFRto2KcumxgiTFwIcCdoInUAc1GYLJUc5S0KqGRwWyooAApUH2IAERjcJxL2QYrvWXbamAAffUu38wBKGBTGzINznH43WIAOh6mFoNDoolSkmkP0YAKB0xsAHosVEQDAFixMJI1hEbFkYJh0BBYSCYGDXhDcND7HCEaxHuVhmjAWTMTBQJAQFhIegQKsGYYmZDxszZvNwH8+TkskA)

All I'm trying to to is to get this to pass error-free, while getting the code suggestions based on `EmailBounceBannerProps`

[image: error message from the above link]

I'm pretty sure I've successfully done something like this before, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm also not sure what this practice or code pattern is called, so my googling so far hasn't led to any successful results.

Does anyone have a solution, or a better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that `possibleBannerTypes` is going to be widened to `string[]`, we need an `as const` to keep the the literal types.

The second problem is that since you union with `BannerProps` on the branch `bannerData.type === 'emailBounce'` you haven't really narrowed anything, since `bannerData` could still be either `EmailBounceBannerProps` or `BannerProps`. And this means `data` will be `unknown | { reason: string }` which will just be `unknown`.

You need a default case that excludes any of the known cases from the `type` property. You could use `Exclude` to type the `type` of this default interface and use it instead of `BannerProps` in the union:

```
const possibleBannerTypes = ['emailBounce', 'anotherBanner'] as const;

interface BannerProps {
  type: typeof possibleBannerTypes[number];
  data?: unknown
}

interface DefaultBannerProps extends BannerProps {
  type: Exclude<typeof possibleBannerTypes[number], EmailBounceBannerProps['type']>; // really just 'anotherBanner' 
}

interface EmailBounceBannerProps extends BannerProps{
  type: 'emailBounce';
  data: {
    reason: string;
  };
}

function test(bannerData: EmailBounceBannerProps | DefaultBannerProps) {
    if (bannerData.type === 'anotherBanner') {
        // do something
    } else if (bannerData.type === 'emailBounce') {
        console.log(bannerData.data.reason)
    }
}
```

Comment: You know if there is a better way with an `enum` here ? instead of create multiple interface

Comment: `string` vs `enum` will not matter much IMO the problem will be the same